# Why would the firefox of my running system automatically open files from an external USB drive that used to be the boot-drive of another system?

Tags: luks, disk-encryption, external-hdd, bootable, dolphin

I have an SSD that another laptop was booting from (before the other hardware in that laptop failed)
but now I'm using it in [one of those little SATA enclosure shell adapter things](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/61UYObLYdGS.jpg)
in order to access the data from that system by mounting it as an external USB data-drive on *this* system.

However, yesterday when I had it mounted,
I noticed my firefox bizarrely lagging and slowing to a crawl...

I only figured out it was because of the external drive when I went to unmount it,
and found files were still in use on it,
and by *firefox* for some bizarre reason,
even though I had definitely never opened anything from it in firefox.

So my only guesses are...

---

There might be some sort of... symlink/hardlink confusion?
like, with some files that *used to* get opened by the firefox on *that* system
back when the external drive was the internal boot-drive of my other (now dead) computer?

But I honestly don't *really* know what "hardlinks" even *are* really,
beyond the fact that they exist...

---

I *think* the problem started *after* I did a bunch of `find` and `grep` (well, `ag`) stuff in the drive?
but I'm not sure...

---

And it *separately* occurs to me that *maybe* it was related to some "helpful" thing my dolphin file browser might've tried to do "behind the scenes" when I used its GUI mounting tools?
(
But I didn't *click* on any files in dolphin,
and I would've *noticed* if I accidentally clicked some html file and it opened up in firefox,
and anyway,
while it was lagging, I had already tried making sure every firefox window was on a new tab and suspending everything else
(using the addon https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-discard-suspender/?utm_content=addons-manager-reviews-link&utm_medium=firefox-browser&utm_source=firefox-browser)
)

---

And the final maybe-relevant thing that occurs to me is:
the drive is encrypted, so maybe it's related to the whole "`luks`" thing?

But I *barely* know anything about disk encryption, "`luks`", or "`mapper`",
beyond the fact that they *exist*,
sooo... yeah, I dunno.

---

Finaly, while it was still running, I found in the output of `lsof` like:

```
 COMMAND     PID   TID TASKCMD         USER   FD      TYPE             DEVICE  SIZE/OFF       NODE NAME  
 firefox   28238  5369 IndexedDB       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238  5381 StreamT~n       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238  5382 IndexedDB       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238  5391 WRScene~l       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238  5392 WRScene~e       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238  5393 WRRende~k       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238  5394 WRScene~l       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238  5395 WRScene~e       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238  5396 WRRende~k       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238  5399 IndexedDB       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238  5575 IndexedDB       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238  5708 IndexedDB       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238  5715 IndexedDB       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28244 pool-spaw       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28245 gmain           user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28246 gdbus           user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28247 glean.dis       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28249 IPC\x20I/       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28250 Timer           user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28251 Netlink         user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28252 Socket          user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28253 IPDL\x20B       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28255 HTML5\x20       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28258 JS\x20Wat       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28267 Cache2          user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28268 Cookie          user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28278 TaskCon~l       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28279 TaskCon~l       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28283 Worker          user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28292 firefox:r       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28293 firefox:d       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28294 GLXVsyncT       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28295 CanvasRen       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28296 Renderer        user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28297 WRWorker#       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28298 WRWorker#       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28299 WRWorkerL       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28300 WRWorkerL       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28301 Composito       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28302 ImageIO         user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28305 Permissio       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28306 Breakpad        user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28307 SandboxRe       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28308 IPC\x20La       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28335 QuotaMana       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28338 FSBroker2       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28362 TRR\x20Ba       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28399 GMPThread       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28400 ImageBrid       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28401 FSBroker2       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28402 ProcessHa       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28403 WRScene~i       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28404 WRScene~d       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28405 WRRende~c       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28422 AudioIP~v       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28423 AudioIP~a       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28424 AudioIP~i       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28435 threaded-       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28437 Backgro~P       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28438 ProxyReso       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28444 FSBroker2       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28446 WRScene~i       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28447 WRScene~d       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28448 WRRende~c       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28459 WRScene~i       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28460 WRScene~d       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28461 WRRende~c       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28467 WRScene~i       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28468 WRScene~d       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28469 WRRende~c       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28470 WRScene~i       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28471 WRScene~d       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28472 WRRende~c       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28473 WRScene~i       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28474 WRScene~d       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28475 WRRende~c       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28476 WRScene~i       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28477 WRScene~d       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28478 WRRende~c       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28481 FSBroker2       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28484 FSBroker2       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28530 URL\x20Cl       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28548 mozStorag       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28551 FSBroker2       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28559 LS\x20Thr       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28560 mozStorag       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28562 mozStorag       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28649 mozStorag       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28678 DOM\x20Wo       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28703 MemoryPol       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28706 glean.mps       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28834 RemoteLzy       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 28838 DOM\x20Wo       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29093 mozStorag       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29113 mozStorag       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29178 FSBroker2       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29276 FSBroker2       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29278 FSBroker2       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29422 DOMCacheT       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29595 SwComposi       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29596 WRScene~i       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29597 WRScene~d       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29598 WRRende~c       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29599 mozStorag       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29600 mozStorag       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29641 threaded-       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29642 SwComposi       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29643 WRScene~i       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29644 WRScene~d       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29645 WRRende~c       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29688 SwComposi       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29689 WRScene~l       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29690 WRScene~e       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29691 WRRende~k       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29747 FSBroker2       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29748 FSBroker2       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 29986 FSBroker2       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 30067 FSBroker3       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 30230 WRScene~l       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 30231 WRScene~e       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 30232 WRRende~k       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 30373 FSBroker3       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 31425 FSBroker3       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 31930 FSBroker3       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 32387 FSBroker3       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 32436 FSBroker3       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc  
 firefox   28238 32457 BgIOThr~o       user  cwd       DIR              254,0      4096          2 /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community What? I think the core "specific problem" is clear (firefox on my running system mysteriously automatically opens files on the boot-drive for another system that's mounted as a data-drive). The rest *is* exactly that "enough detail to identify an adequate answer" -- all the potentially relevant guesses/information I could think of that might be necessary to figure out that specific problem. ... oh, you're a bot? Telling me to do what I already did as best as I could? Weird...

Comment: you problem probably has nothing to do with Firefox ... the real question is `why is /run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc on a removable drive?`

Comment: @jsotola ... ohhh, then it *must* be related to how I mounted it with dolphin! Thanks, I think I could figure it out from just that! Okay, I just need to look up how you're *supposed* to mount an an encrypted partition on external data-drive properly from the commandline...

Comment: (@jsotola yeah, I just [answered my own question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/751901/571754) as completely as I was able to, given that I'm just learning this all myself right now.)

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by the fact that I initially mounted the encrypted partition by simply clicking on it in dolphin's GUI tool
(nothing to do with firefox *specifically*, I just *noticed* it because of firefox.)

To fix:

---

First, check you already have installed the package `cryptsetup`.

---

But if you just jump ahead to trying:
$ `sudo cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sdd2 chosen_name`
you'll just get
#=>

```
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdd2: [<entered>]  
Cannot use device /dev/sdd2 which is in use (already mapped or mounted).
```

And if you check like:
$ `ls /dev/mapper`
you'll see like:
#=>
`control  luks-5deb0f6a-2f8d-4034-94d1-d7d77f9039d3`

So you need to *un*-map that first.

cf [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11130096)

> You may have to also use `dmsetup` to remove the device mapping.
> Easiest way, **if it doesn't interfere with any other mappings** is to use a `dmsetup remove_all`.

(My emphasis.)

Since I only have the one mapping listed, I just tried that:
$ `sudo dmsetup remove_all`

and checking afterwards:
$ `ls /dev/mapper`
#=>
`control`

---

*Now* you can do something like:
 `sudo cryptsetup open --type luks [<device path>] [<name you choose>]`
like
$ `sudo cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sdd2 chosen_name`
#=>

```
[sudo] password for root: [<entered>]  
Enter passphrase for /dev/sdd2: [<entered>]
```

and check:
$ `ls /dev/mapper`
#=>
`control  chosen_name`

(
and `lsblk` will show it as something like:

```
[...]  
├─sdd2                                           part     crypto_LUKS  
│ └─chosen_name                                  crypt    ext4  
[...]
```

rather than something like:

```
[...]  
├─sdd2                                           part     crypto_LUKS  
│ └─luks-5deb0f6a-2f8d-4034-94d1-d7d77f9039d3    crypt    ext4  
[...]
```

)

(
cf [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/63598/1713490),
although the manpage says that's the "old syntax":
`luksOpen <device> <name> (old syntax)`
and the new is:
`open --type luks <device> <name>`
)

---

And now you can just use `mount` the way you normally would (to any empty directory you want as a mountpoint),
like:
`mount [<device>] [<mountpoint]`
just swapping out the bit:
`[<device>]`
for:
`dev/mapper/[<name you choose>]`

eg:
$ `mkdir ~/my_mountpoint`
$ `sudo mount /dev/mapper/chosen_name ~/my_mountpoint`

(Check with like $ `ls ~/my_mountpoint` or whatever.)

---

See the rest of [that answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/63598/1713490) for unmounting etc,
although again, I think that
$ `sudo cryptsetup luksClose chosen_name`
is the "old syntax",
although the manpage doesn't seem to *mention* `luksClose` at all anymore...

It now only mentions:

```
CLOSE  
       close <name>  
       See cryptsetup-close(8).
```

but $ `man cryptsetup-close` says:

```
For backward compatibility, there are close command aliases: remove, plainClose, luksClose, loopaesClose, tcryptClose, bitlkClose (all behave exactly the same, device type is determined automatically from the  
       active device).
```

so I *think* you can still just use it that way?

...
I just tried:
$ `sudo umount ~/my_mountpoint`
$ `sudo cryptsetup luksClose chosen_name`
and it just went:
#=>
`Device chosen_name is not active.`

And then I was immediately able to mount it again without entering the password,
so I dunno??

And I honestly don't really care enough right now, so yeah.

---

---

Open questions my answer here doesn't address:

- How do you *actually* "lock the container" again?
- Does the mapper point set with $ `sudo cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sdd2 chosen_name` persist across reboots or whatever?
  (and if not, how do you make it if you want it to?)
  (
  cuz I haven't made *completely* sure that that "new syntax" I used:
  $ `sudo cryptsetup open --type luks /dev/sdd2 chosen_name`
  is indeed just a alias to the "old syntax":
  $ `sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdd2 chosen_name`
  (although you'd think it is?)
  )
- While the new mapper "chosen_name" is set,
  will GUI tools like dolphin respect it?
  (ie, clicking on the drive in the dolphin sidebar will mount it to a sane location...)

... no, it still asks for a password when you click on it
(even though that's no longer required from the commandline now that it's unlocked)
and it mounts it to like `/run/media/user/1c5afe56-1888-48dd-aae4-3cafce30b9cc/`
which I'm pretty sure is *not* sane.

Just looking at *all* the available columns `lsblk`'s help has, I see three that mention my `chosen_name`:
`ID-LINK=dm-name-chosen_name`
`ID=name-chosen_name`
`PATH=/dev/mapper/chosen_name`
|
So I *guess* one of those (probably "`PATH`"?) is what you should use if you want to add it to your `/etc/fstab`?
... No, not `PATH`, let's try `ID`...
...
Okay I stopped caring for now. Would have to grind through `man fstab` and follow up on `fs_spec` etc.
|
I'll just do it manually through the commandline for now.

---

---

TODO: fill in the obvious gaps in this answer, or find a tutorial to link to that does so.